# Equivalent of docker-compose.yml parameters in Docker Cloud

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-cloud

I started playing with Docker Cloud and am trying to deploy a [tomav/docker-mailserver](https://github.com/tomav/docker-mailserver) container to an EC2 instance. The EC2 and dockercloud-agent seems to work fine for container deployment.

The docker-compose.yml uses *hostname* and *domainname* parameters which are required to properly configure it, but I can't find their equivalent in Docker Cloud's interface.

One of them is using the container auto-generated name, which I need to override.

Anybody knows if I am missing something ? Or is it not possible yet ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is [a stack file](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/feature-reference/stack-yaml-reference/), roughly equivalent to docker-compose

Comment: Looks like I overlooked the Stack thing. Thanks !